# C# EF Navigation Properties on Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have limited knowledge about Entity Framework and running in to some issues with my object relation. I have the following entities:

```
public class Reseller
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ResellerLevel? ResellerLevel { get; set; }
  public ResellerLevel? HosterLevel { get; set; }

  public ResellerMail Mail { get; set; }
  public virtual ObservableCollection<ResellerMail> Mails { get; set; }

  public Reseller()
  {
    Mails = new ObservableCollection<ResellerMail>();
  }
}

public class ResellerMail
{
  [Key, ForeignKey("Reseller")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Mail { get; set; }
  public string Display
  {
    get
    {
      return String.Format("{0} <{1}>", Name, Mail);
    }
  }

  public virtual Reseller Reseller { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to attain the following 2 relations:

- One-to-Many between Reseller and Mail:
  Basically a list of mails linked to the reseller.
- One-to-One relation
  The selected mail of the reseller, from a dropdown list. It could be just the Id of the mail, but I want to attach a navigation property to it.

How would I go about something like this?

Comment: All your data relationships are working fine with the above set up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `ObservableCollection` in your models because this type is used to interact with the UI (which you should not do directly from your Models).

As for the two questions:

For 1:
Just set a virtual collection for the `ResellerEmail`. This means your model will look like this:

```
public class Reseller
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ResellerLevel? ResellerLevel { get; set; }
  public ResellerLevel? HosterLevel { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<ResellerMail> Mails { get; set; }

  public Reseller()
  {
    Mails = new ICollection<ResellerMail>();
  }
}
```

For no2. You could have an object of type `Reseller` below the `ForeignKey`. You can try something like:

```
 [Key, ForeignKey("Reseller")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Reseller Reseller { get; set; }
```